# Ng-Click not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-controlleras

whenever I click my submit button nothing happens, currently all I want it to do is print out the username and password to test there bindings. 
And I am able to talk to the controller and print out hard coded message that I made in the controller, it seem's that the ng-click doesn't fire on that method.
Any help would be great,
Thanks :D

```
<section id="register-view" class="mainbar">
    <section class="matter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <label>{{vm.message}}</label>
                <form class="register-form">
                    <label name="username_label"> Username: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="vm.userDetails.username"/>
                    <br/>
                    <label name="password_label"> Password: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="vm.userDetails.password"/>
                    <br/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.submitUserDetails()">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

And controller class

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.register')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['$q', 'dataservice', 'logger'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function RegisterController($q, dataservice, logger) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'baass';
        vm.userDetails = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }

        function activate() {
            var promises = [submitUserDetails()];
            return $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                logger.info('Activated Dashboard View');
            });
        }

        function submitUserDetails() {
            console.log('Username: ' + vm.userDetails.username);
            console.log('Password: ' + vm.userDetails.password);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: check the console that you don't have any error in the page

Comment: I have there is nothing coming up in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `submitUserDetails` in controller context to make it available on view, as you only defined the function of `submitUserDetails`. You should bind its reference to `vm.submitUserDetails`

```
vm.submitUserDetails = submitUserDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

the function needs to be attached to the $scope

```
$scope.function submitUserDetails() {
        console.log('Username: ' + vm.userDetails.username);
        console.log('Password: ' + vm.userDetails.password);
    }
```

Comment: This is partially correct, he is using this with `control as`.  To use `$scope` he would need to extend `$scope` into his controller and that may not be desired in this instance.

Comment: are you saying he would need to add $scope as a controller dependency?

Comment: Correct, and that would been it would inherit all of the parent `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few issues with your code, but the biggest one is that those functions are not actually attached to 'this' (`vm` as you've called it in your code). So, they can't be accessed by the scope, because they're only accessible inside the RegisterController function.

To solve this, I would add this code to the bottom of your function:

```
this.activate = activate;
this.submitUserDetails = submitUserDetails;
```

As well, `submitUserDetails()` should be returning a promise, no? I expect that's causing some funky behavior as well.

Comment: No, this is just a test to see if my binding are working, I am not returning anything yet